# What are the options to cache random data in a browser environment?

Tags: caching, browser

If I happen to retrieve a bunch of random data (text in my case), what are all the options for caching it across page loads?

Currently I can think of:

- localStorage
- indexedDb
- userData

Basically these are the key factors:

- As much storage as possible
- Store it for a day at least
- Can be done programmatically with JavaScript
- As high cross-browser solution as possible

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to create this in HTML5 only, supporting only modern browsers, I would advice ["Mark Pilgrim's DiveIntoHTML5 chapter on Web Storage"](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). Since this is the only official standard, it has an advantage over custom browser-specific storage options.